# Where does Z_int come from?

Tags: c++, c, perl-module

I've been browsing a lot of perl C library extensions and have noticed, especially in Date::Calc, that Z_int and Z_long and the like are the standard (vs 'int' and 'long').

I'm assuming this is some POSIX standard but Google has failed me for a while now trying to find a definition or source for this syntax. Do you know where this comes from, or have a good reference for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a standard thing; I think it's just [Steffen Beyer](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/)'s personal notation that he uses in a number of his modules (including `Date::Calc`). The `Z` here is the math sense of **Z** to denote the set of integers; `Z_int` is `signed int`, whereas `N_int` (from **N**, the set of natural numbers) is `unsigned int`. All these `typedef`s are defined in [the header file `Toolbox.h`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/STBEY/Date-Calc-XS-6.2/ToolBox.h) in the modules that use them.

Comment: Thank you! I feel sorta silly for missing that header file definition, but am still glad I asked